# How to get and save constants?

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to initialize constants and get across application in cakephp.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Configure Class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/42/The-Configuration-Class)

You can use Configure to read/write values available across the application. As [dhofstet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68234/dhofstet) mentioned, a good place to do this is in app/config/bootstrap.php

Mariano Iglesias wrote a [very good article](http://cricava.com/blogs/index.php?blog=6&title=using_configure_on_your_cakephp_applicat&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) about this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, one place to define your application-wide constants is

> app/config/bootstrap.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your constants in `app/config/bootstrap.php` or in `app/config/core.php` (I believe the former is preferred, but either one works).  The syntax for defining a constant is:

```
define('MY_CONSTANT','my value');
```